# How to remove duplicate timestamp overlaps and add column in the original dataframe from zipped list findings

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timestamp

I have two columns in my dataframe 'START_TIME' and 'END_TIME' which i zipped into a list and brought it to the below form. Used the following snippet to generate that.

```
zippedList = list(zip(new_df['START_TIME'],new_df['END_TIME']))
```

```
[(Timestamp('2020-06-09 06:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-06-09 16:00:00')),
 (Timestamp('2020-06-09 02:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-06-09 06:00:00')),
 (Timestamp('2020-06-10 02:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-06-10 06:00:00')),
 (Timestamp('2020-06-09 16:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-06-10 02:00:00')),
 (Timestamp('2020-06-10 06:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-06-10 16:00:00')),
 (Timestamp('2020-06-10 16:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-06-11 02:00:00')),
 (Timestamp('2020-06-11 02:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-06-11 06:00:00')),
 (Timestamp('2020-06-11 01:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-06-11 05:00:00')),
 (Timestamp('2020-06-11 06:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-06-11 16:00:00')),
 (Timestamp('2020-06-11 16:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-06-12 02:00:00'))]
```

I went on to iterate through this list and find overlapping values too through this one

```
for elem1 in zippedList:
    for elem2 in zippedList:
        #print(elem1,elem2)
        i1= pd.Interval(elem1[0],elem1[1],closed='neither')
        i2= pd.Interval(elem2[0],elem2[1],closed='neither')
        if (i1.overlaps(i2)) and elem1!=elem2:
            print('OVERLAP FOUND!!')
            print(i1,i2)
```

Got these duplicated overlaps.

```
OVERLAP FOUND!!
(2020-06-10 16:00:00, 2020-06-11 02:00:00) (2020-06-11 01:00:00, 2020-06-11 05:00:00)
OVERLAP FOUND!!
(2020-06-11 02:00:00, 2020-06-11 06:00:00) (2020-06-11 01:00:00, 2020-06-11 05:00:00)
OVERLAP FOUND!!
(2020-06-11 01:00:00, 2020-06-11 05:00:00) (2020-06-10 16:00:00, 2020-06-11 02:00:00)
OVERLAP FOUND!!
(2020-06-11 01:00:00, 2020-06-11 05:00:00) (2020-06-11 02:00:00, 2020-06-11 06:00:00)
```

I have a couple of questions here.

1. How do I avoid these duplicate overlaps found. For instance, **(2020-06-11 02:00:00, 2020-06-11 06:00:00) (2020-06-11 01:00:00, 2020-06-11 05:00:00)** and **(2020-06-11 01:00:00, 2020-06-11 05:00:00) (2020-06-11 02:00:00, 2020-06-11 06:00:00)** are the same!
2. How do I create a boolean column in the original dataframe (new_df) to mark **True** for all timestamp pairs which have been found to have overlapped. For instance, along the rows **Timestamp('2020-06-11 02:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-06-11 06:00:00'))** and **(Timestamp('2020-06-11 01:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-06-11 05:00:00'))**, should be marked as True. How do i achieve this?
   Note that the overlap findings are performed with the zipped list(zippedList) and not with my dataframe(new_df).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please clarify: what do you actually want to do? for each pair of timestamps (i.e. time interval), you want to check if it overlaps with *any other* interval?

Comment: Yes exactly! But in addition to that, I want a column a column added in my original dataframe (new_df) which shows me 'True' for all the overlapping timestamps (i believe the questions are lucid!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're just interested if there is an overlap (and not how many), you can break the inner for loop as soon as you find an overlap. Create the boolean mask as you check for overlaps in the nested for loops.

```
import pandas as pd

zippedList = (
    [(pd.Timestamp('2020-06-09 06:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2020-06-09 16:00:00')),
     (pd.Timestamp('2020-06-09 02:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2020-06-09 06:00:00')),
     (pd.Timestamp('2020-06-10 02:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2020-06-10 06:00:00')),
     (pd.Timestamp('2020-06-09 16:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2020-06-10 02:00:00')),
     (pd.Timestamp('2020-06-10 06:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2020-06-10 16:00:00')),
     (pd.Timestamp('2020-06-10 16:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2020-06-11 02:00:00')),
     (pd.Timestamp('2020-06-11 02:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2020-06-11 06:00:00')),
     (pd.Timestamp('2020-06-11 01:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2020-06-11 05:00:00')),
     (pd.Timestamp('2020-06-11 06:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2020-06-11 16:00:00')),
     (pd.Timestamp('2020-06-11 16:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2020-06-12 02:00:00'))]
    )

# map to intervals before looping
intervals = list(map(lambda i: pd.Interval(i[0], i[1], closed='neither'), zippedList))

m = []
for i1 in intervals:
    for i2 in intervals:
        if (i1.overlaps(i2)) and i1 != i2:
            m.append(True)
            break
    else: # else clause will only be called if break wasn't executed
        m.append(False)

for b, t in zip(m, zippedList):
    if b:
        print(t)

# (Timestamp('2020-06-10 16:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-06-11 02:00:00'))
# (Timestamp('2020-06-11 02:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-06-11 06:00:00'))
# (Timestamp('2020-06-11 01:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-06-11 05:00:00'))
```

Now you can make `m` a column of your df, i.e. `new_df['OVERLAPS'] = m`