# How to convert a list of tuples with interval type to DateTime in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, datetime

I have a list of tuples as shown below with Interval type.

```
[(Interval('2020-06-10 16:00:00', '2020-06-11 02:00:00', closed='neither'),
  Interval('2020-06-11 01:00:00', '2020-06-11 05:00:00', closed='neither')),
 (Interval('2020-06-11 02:00:00', '2020-06-11 06:00:00', closed='neither'),
  Interval('2020-06-11 01:00:00', '2020-06-11 05:00:00', closed='neither')),
 (Interval('2020-06-11 01:00:00', '2020-06-11 05:00:00', closed='neither'),
  Interval('2020-06-10 16:00:00', '2020-06-11 02:00:00', closed='neither'))]
```

How do I unzip this, remove the duplicate pairs present and convert this to datetime format as **two separate columns** to get something like this?

```
        START_TIME             END_TIME
0   2020-06-10 16:00:00  2020-06-11 02:00:00
1   2020-06-11 02:00:00  2020-06-11 06:00:00
2   2020-06-11 01:00:00  2020-06-11 05:00:00
```

It's more like I want to know how to convert Interval data type to Datetime and Timestamp format.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This isn't valid? `ValueError: Only numeric, Timestamp and Timedelta endpoints are allowed when constructing an Interval.`

Comment: I zipped the START_TIME and END_TIME, had a few computations with them using pd.Interval and then my resultant list ended up like this. So there should be a method to convert it back to Datetime!

Comment: why don't you start [where you left off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62570933/how-to-remove-duplicate-timestamp-overlaps-and-add-column-in-the-original-datafr)?

Comment: Why is your list nested and not flat?

Comment: it contains a pair of values actually. like (s1,e1) and (s2,e2)

Comment: referring to my answer on your question linked above, you should be able to get your desired output as simple as `new_df2 = new_df[new_df['OVERLAPS']]` or `new_df2 = new_df[m]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
# flatten the list
lst = [e for x in lst for e in x]

# extract start and end time. 
df = pd.DataFrame([(t.left, t.right) for t in lst])

df.drop_duplicates(inplace = True)

# rename columns
df.columns = ["start_time", "end_time"]
```

The output is:

```
           start_time            end_time
0 2020-06-10 16:00:00 2020-06-11 02:00:00
1 2020-06-11 01:00:00 2020-06-11 05:00:00
2 2020-06-11 02:00:00 2020-06-11 06:00:00
```